# case-when in pyspark checking against several tables

Tags: python, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I would like to know how can I do the below sql code in pyspark?

In sql, I've created several tables inside the query.

Can I do it in pyspark avoiding the creation of several dfs? An id can be in none, all or some of the time periods (I have 5 time periods).

```
create table mytable as
select p.id, 
    case when t1.id is not null then 1 else 0 end as active_period_1,
    case when t2.id is not null then 1 else 0 end as active_period_2

from
(select id from table1) p
left join (select id from initial_table where buy_date>='2018-01-01' and 
 buy_date<'2019-01-01') t1  on p.id= t1.id
left join (select id from initial_table where buy_date>='2017-01-01' and 
 buy_date<'2018-01-01') t2  on p.id= t2.id
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can do it like this, left join of initial_table, after filtering the right date, selecting the column id and creating a column active_period_1 filled with 1. Same operation for active_period_2, and finally fill missing values of both columns with 0.

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

mytable = table1.select('id') \
                .join(initial_table.filter( (F.col(buy_date) >= F.to_date('2018-01-01'))
                                            & (F.col(buy_date) < F.to_date('2019-01-01')) )\
                                   .select('id')\
                                   .withColumn('active_period_1', F.lit(1)),
                       on = ['id'], how='left')\
                .join(initial_table.filter( (F.col(buy_date) >= F.to_date('2017-01-01'))
                                            & (F.col(buy_date) < F.to_date('2018-01-01')) )\
                                   .select('id')\
                                   .withColumn('active_period_2', F.lit(1)),
                       on = ['id'], how='left')\
                .fillna(0, subset=['active_period_1', 'active_period_2'])
```

Comment: Hi Ben, thanks but I need to create a df as the table in my code would be. One column for the id and then 1 column per period.

Comment: @DroppingOff not sure I understand, the code provided should have 3 columns: one id with all the ids from table1 and 2 columns active_period_x. Can you explain more what I misunderstood?

Comment: Actually it is me who did not undertand your answer. I will mark it as answer now. Thanks